# How to close Eclipse e4 Part,When Preferences Window is opend

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

When I open Preferences and update config I need close "old" Part. But I encounter a problem. Eclipse throws an exception that tells me it does not active Window!

What should I do?

```
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not have an active window
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.getActiveWindowService(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.hidePart(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:142)
    at cn.oge.kdm.proapp.application.analysis.platform.preference.editor.PlatformAddressPreferencePage$5.widgetSelected(PlatformAddressPreferencePage.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the Application `EPartService` to try and close a part. This will not work when a dialog is open as there is no active window which the application part service needs.

Instead you need to use the part service for the top level window. Get this using something like:

```java
@Inject
EModelService modelService;
@Inject
MApplication application;

MWindow window = (MWindow)modelService.find("id of your top level window", application);

EPartService partService = window.getContext().get(EPartService.class);
```